# Как работать во второй форме?

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api

В программировании новичок, поэтому любой совет в написании кода восприму с благодарностью! Пишу прогу для получения списка друзей из VK.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string email = txtlogin.Text.ToString();
            string pass = txtpass.Text.ToString();
            var api = new VkApi();
            Settings settings = Settings.All;
            int appId = appid;
            Form2 form2;
            form2 = new Form2();

            if (txtlogin.Text != "" || txtpass.Text != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    api.Authorize(appId, email, pass, settings); 
                }

                catch
                { 
                    MessageBox.Show("Неверный логин или пароль"); 
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Заполните поля", "");
            }
            form2.Show();//открываю вторую форму после успешной авторизации
            this.Hide();// закрываем первую форму      
        }
```

Как я думаю и это наверное очевидно,что вторая форма не видит, что авторизация успешно пройдена и можно обращаться к вк.

Вопрос, как мне быть? Спасибо!

Вот, что я пишу во второй форме:

```
 var api = new VkApi();
        var group = api.Utils.ResolveScreenName("etorostov");
        long id = group.Id.Value;
        int totalCount = 1;
        int count = 5;

        var wallpost = api.Wall.Get(-id, out totalCount, count);
        foreach (var one in wallpost)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(one.Text);
        }
```

Выдает ошибку

```
An unhandled exception of type 'VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException' occurred in VkNet.dll
```

Comment: в каком виде она должна "видеть" что авторизация пройдена? Она должна открываться только если авторизация прошла успешно?

Comment: После авторизации она открывается, все ок. Ну как мне дальше работать? Вторая же форма не знает ,что авторизация прошла и все ок?

Comment: ну значит открывайте ее только в случае успешной авторизации, как я вам ответе предложил (и как задумывалось, судя по вашим комментам в коде). Тогда вторая форма всегда будет знать что все ок, и работать она может начинать вот прямо после открытия - потому что в случае "не ок" она бы не открылась.

Comment: ок, давайте с другой стороны. что должно произойти при **неуспешной** авторизации? вторая форма должна при этом показаться? что происходит дальше? пользователь подправляет имя и пароль и опять нажимает кнопку? вторая форма может что-то сделать, пока авторизация не пройдена?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException' occurred in VkNet.dll во второй форме он выдает такую ошибку

Comment: ну. т.е. вторая форма неработоспособна если логин не прошел. значит ее не надо показывать. значит попробуйте сделать так, как я вам написал в ответе. ну или как-то сформулируйте что должно происходить при неуспешном логине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вторая форма вообще не работоспособна, если логин не прошел. Значит она не должна отображаться в этом случае. Переставьте создание и отображение второй формы в `if`, тогда она будет отображаться только после успешного входа.

в первой форме:

```
if (txtlogin.Text != "" || txtpass.Text != "")
{
    try
    {
        api.Authorize(appId, email, pass, settings); 

        Form2 form2;
        form2 = new Form2(api);
        form2.Show();//открываю вторую форму после успешной авторизации
        this.Hide();// закрываем первую форму
    }
    catch
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Неверный логин или пароль"); 
    }   
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Заполните поля", "");
}
```

Во второй форме добавьте свойство и параметр в конструктора типа параметр `VkApi`:

```
VkApi Api { get; set; }

public Form2(VkApi api)
{
    this.Api = api;

    // тут то, что уже есть в конструкторе
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

... и используйте тот же объект про работе из второй формы:

```
var api = this.Api; // <-- то, что передали из form1 через конструктор

var group = api.Utils.ResolveScreenName("etorostov");
long id = group.Id.Value;
int totalCount = 1;
int count = 5;

var wallpost = api.Wall.Get(-id, out totalCount, count);
foreach (var one in wallpost)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(one.Text);
}
```

кстати, использование исключений для нормального control flow - это нехорошо. Метод `Authorize` должен возвращать `bool`, а не падать с исключением в вполне нормальной (с точки зрения программы) ситуации - неправильном логине и пароле.

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли, форма вторая открывается, как мне сделать так ,чтобы она видела,что авторизация  успешна пройдена и можно уже работать с вкапи?

Comment: что значит "видела"?

Comment: VkNet.Exception.AccessTokenInvalidException

Comment: вы пробовали решение из ответа?

Comment: Да все хорошо но вторая форма выкидывает с ошибкой

Comment: Ну значит проблема уже не в открывании и не в форме - убедитесь что вы используете тот же объект VkApi, а не создаете новый

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23614/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-pashapash).